# Mismatch between Cassandra table uuid in linux file directory and system_schema.tables

Tags: cassandra

we have detected that table-uuid in linux file directory is different from `system_schema.tables` id.
I have executed `nodetool describecluster` and see only one schema version in the cluster.
How we can fix this issue do anyone has any idea? Restarting the nodes only create a new empty directory with name system_schema.tables id directory but in this case i have two directories old one has sstables with incorrect uuid new one has correct uuid but empty.
thanks in advance

I have tried restarting of all nodes one by one but in this case i have two directories old one has sstables with incorrect uuid new one has correct uuid but empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the IDs for the same table, it indicates that the table has been dropped then recreated so the table now has a new UUID. For example, here are two directories on the filesystem for the same table name:

```
  myks/
    mytable-e5da398083eb11ec8c561b3845d1a791/
    mytable-166fbf50b68211ee9ec10800200c9a66/
```

The IDs in the directory names are [version 1 UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) which means they contain a timestamp that embeds the time when the table was created (introduced in Cassandra 2.1 by [CASSANDRA-5202](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5202)).

In the first example above (`mytable-e5da398083eb11ec8c561b3845d1a791`), the corresponding table ID and its equivalent creation time is:

```
e5da3980-83eb-11ec-8c56-1b3845d1a791 = 02 Feb 2022 05:49:33 GMT
```

whereas for the second example (`mytable-166fbf50b68211ee9ec10800200c9a66`):

```
166fbf50-b682-11ee-9ec1-0800200c9a66 = 19 Jan 2024 04:20:33 GMT
```

The table `mytable` was originally created in February 2022 and at some point was dropped then recreated in January 2024. The most likely reason for dropping/recreating a table is that it needed to be created with a new schema. If so, there is nothing to "fix" because it isn't broken and is working as designed -- CASSANDRA-5202 appends a UUID to the table's directory name to prevent data (SSTables) from the old version of the table from being loaded and possibly leading to errors such as schema disagreement or unexpected data types.

However, IF you believe that the schema of the table's old version is identical to the schema of the newly created table, then you should be able to "reload" the data as follows:

1. On the first node, force all memtables to be flushed to disk with `nodetool drain`.
2. Shutdown Cassandra on the node.
3. Copy the SSTables from the old directory to the new directory.
4. Start Cassandra.

**WARNING** - Only perform these steps if you are absolutely sure that the schema between the two versions of the table are identical. Otherwise, you will risk running into errors when Cassandra reads the contents of the SSTables. Cheers!

Comment: For example in system_schema.tables i see this uuid mytable-166fbf50b68211ee9ec10800200c9a66 but in linux file directory i see only one (not two directories) and a totally different uuid lets say for example mytable-e5da398083eb11ec8c561b3845d1a791.

after i have restarted the node i see cassandra created correct uuid folder in linux file system like "mytable-166fbf50b68211ee9ec10800200c9a66" but it is empty. And now i cannot see any data in table by checking it from cqlsh

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you need to copy the SSTables from the old to the new directory. Cheers!

Comment: Since there exists only 1 directory so i cannot copy from one to another. Do you have any solution with only 1 mismatched directory?
thanks